# Create Project in Atom Editor

Tags: github, editor, atom-editor

Recently I moved from **Sublime Text** to **GitHub Atom** editor. I wanted to create new project in Atom editor. How do I do it?

Is there any way to migrate Sublime Text project files to Atom project files?

Comment: I envy you, atom editor user... :(

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey its totally open source now :) and no invites required of course

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**YES**

Project management Sublime Style:

`apm install project-manager`

Comment: Oh, super, thanks! I misunderstand `apm` with `npm` :-)

Answer (score 8):

This is what you're looking for. With this package you can easily change between projects just like in Sublime editor.

https://atom.io/packages/project-manager

Comment: I am using this. But i worked on multiple projects. I want to create project and switch between project just like in sublime text.

Comment: Ok, but that's possible. If you're using command line, just go to the project folder and press atom. If you want to open another project just go there and press atom again. That's it, that is how it works.

Comment: Will it open two atom window?

Comment: i know it. But i do not want to switch between different window. I want to have switch between project like in sublime text2

Comment: I have installed project manager in atom. But I am lost on how to create a python project in atom. Searched google as well. any specific links to start working with Atom and python on windows would help.

Answer (score 6):

For those that are unsatisfied with dealing with multiple atom windows, check out https://atom.io/packages/project-plus

It allows you to switch between projects in the same window (and does it fast). It works almost identical to how sublime did (in that it remembers open buffers, temporary state, tabs, etc.).